# Add character to selected duplicate value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, return-value

I need to add character / number to selected duplicate values.

This is what I need:

```
SELECT Name -- Here I need to add for example 1 if It have duplicates
            -- If It is hard way to code, how to add 1 to all selected values?
FROM Example
WHERE Id BETWEEN 25 AND 285
```

If there are 2 equal names `Peter` It should select `Peter` and second `Peter1`

*If there is no easy way to make It, how to add `1` to all selected lines? Should select `Peter1` instead of `Peter`*

I've tried this:

```
SELECT Name + ' 1' AS Name -- in this case selecting wrong column
FROM Example
WHERE Id BETWEEN 25 AND 285
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT @cols += ([Name]) + ','
    FROM   (SELECT  Name --I neeed to integrate It here
            FROM    FormFields
            WHERE   ID BETWEEN 50 AND 82
            ) a
```

If I use this:

```
SELECT @cols += ([Name]) + ',' -- here throws error
FROM   (SELECT Name + CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), RowNum-1) END AS [UpdatedName]
                FROM (
                SELECT  Name AS Name,  
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) AS "RowNum"
                FROM    FormFields
                WHERE   Id Between 50 And 82) x
        ) a
```

It throws error: `Invalid column name 'Name'.`

**EDIT 2**

It's different tests but some of them have the same criteria. That's why I need It to rename.
[image: howshouldbe]

Comment: Which are you using, `mysql` or `sql server`?

Comment: I'm using SQL server

Comment: Lowest id Peter unchanged, or? And if there are 3 Peter?

Comment: Best way to make that: `1st Peter = Peter; 2nd = Peter2; 3rd = Peter3...` and etc. If this is hard coding would be nice to change all selected values by adding 1 to all of them. I need It because I use `PIVOT` to use rows as columns and column names can't duplicate.

Comment: You the it in a view or you want to update it in the the able after appending ?

Comment: I dont need to update, just for view

Comment: @Infinity Change `SELECT @cols += ([Name]) + ','` to `SELECT @cols += ([UpdatedName]) + ','`  You renamed it in the sub-query.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this via getting the `Row_Number` and using a `Case`.  Here's an example for `SQL Server`:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  Name, Row_Number() Over (Partition By Name Order By Name) RN
    From    Example
    Where   Id Between 25 And 285
)
Select  Case When RN = 1 Then Name Else Name + Cast((RN - 1) As Varchar (3)) End As Name
From    Cte
```

Comment: It throws me error that incorrect syntax. I will update my question with my real code, and maybe you will have solution how to integrate it. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ROW_NUMBER function built into SQL server.

```
select Name + case when RowNum = 1 then '' else CONVERT(varchar(100), RowNum-1) end as "UpdatedName"
from (
select name as "Name",  
       ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name order by name) as "RowNum"
from Example
Where   Id Between 25 And 285) x
```

Please note that this still doesn't guarantee you unique names. Afterall, someone could already have a name of "MyName1", so if you had 2 people with names "MyName" you'd still get 2 "MyName1" with this select statement.

Comment: I got following errors: `Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_qcs, Line 343
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'a'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_qcs, Line 334
Invalid column name 'Name'.` Please, check my updated question with real code, maybe you have ideas how to integrate It on my code?

Comment: Not sure why that would be. Are you using that result in another subquery? Try naming the colum that is returned. Edit made.

Comment: Yes, you are using it as a sub query. So when you perform a function, SQL server no longer uses a column name as the default name of your derived table.

Comment: And for what it's worth, it doesn't look like your code is going to do what you expect anyway. If your goal is to have a comma delimited list of every name in the DB stored in @@Cols, this will not achieve that. My guess is that only the first name will be appended to @@Cols and the rest will be ignored.

Comment: I need It because I use PIVOT to use rows as columns and column names can't duplicate. So I need in any way to change column names after pivoting or before pivoting row names. If It is impossible to change It If have duplicates, I need to know If Is It possible in my way to change all selected names at all? If yes I will try use `IF` and will be good for me. Because duplicates are sorted in groups, what I mean: `Group1: Peter, Nastya, Jeniffer`, `Group2: Peter, Jackson, Jeniffer`. There never will be duplicates in the same group, so I can use `IF (GroupId = 2) ...Add 1 to all names`

Comment: I updated my question again, how I used subquery in subquery and with error message.

Comment: In your derived table you named your computed column "UpdatedName" but in your outer query you referred to it as "Name".  Make it "@cols += ([UpdatedName])" and it should be syntactically correct. I still don't think it will do what you want though.

Answer (score 1):

This is very unusual request, it looks like you are trying to "make car run with wheels on the roof" :)

The root problem is almost sure wrong database design... Pivot is usually used for data summaries. If you have in the same column "Peter" and "Peter" with different meanings, it looks that there is something wrong. Or do you need to differentiate both Peters for any other reason?

I do not understand what are you trying to achieve. If Peter is always Peter, and you just want to avoid duplicities, you can simply use "group by Name". But this is what pivot does automatically... If Peter and Peter have two different meanings (like Peter1 and Peter2), you should think about changing database structure, if possible.

Or try to explain more deeply what are you trying to achieve.

EDIT:

OK, now I understand the desired output. And what is the structure of your source data table(s)? From your schema it is clear that you need to make PIVOT columns based on

```
Testname+groupId
```

or

```
Testname+convert(varchar(100),groupId)
```

if groupId is number. That is your Peter1,Peter2 composition. It will create columns that you need. But I dont't know where testname and groupId are located in your datatables. Do test names correspond to column NAMES or to VALUES stored in DB? Is groupId something like TestId? Again column or value? Provide more info about source data structure, if you need more help, your problem is not so complicated.

Comment: So I've tried to explain in stupid way. It's very hard to explain. I'm working with very very BIG project, here I need to make report. Here are not people names as I gave in example. It's voting criteria . I'm updated my question with schema, maybe It will help you understand why I need It.

Answer (score 1):

Since the columns have group IDs, concatenate the Column name with an Underscore and GroupID as a key value and when you display it, strip the underscore and trailing characters.

Like This:

```
SELECT @cols += ([Name]) + ','
FROM   (SELECT  Name + '_' + CAST(GroupId AS varchar)
        FROM    FormFields
        WHERE   ID BETWEEN 50 AND 82
        ) a
```

I assume you are using this to build a dynamic SQL statement.  I'm not sure what the schema of your FormFields Table is, but if it includes something like the test name you could append an AS [Name] + ' - ' +[TestName] to have the column header be something more useful.  I would say try a PIVOT, but that could get pretty ungainly if the tests don't have the majority of the fields in common...

I also assume you are storing responses to these prompts in a table that looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Responses]
(
 RespID int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
 UserID int NOT NULL,
 FieldID int NOT NULL,
 RespVal int/varchar/whatever NOT NULL
)
```

Then perhaps you have a [Test] table with some test metadata that acts as the primary key for your GroupID Foreign key in your FormFields table.

In your example you show responses across all columns, but I'm not sure how that would work since (unless I'm missing something in your explanation and the inferences I've made to your design) one set of responses would only be populated for one of the groups per row, unless you are aggregating responses, but then by what criteria?  Perhaps the rows correspond to respondents and all respondents are required to answer across all form types.  In that case, your output would work as a PIVOT like this:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(4000) = ''
DECLARE @colList varchar(1000)
DECLARE @selList varchar(1000)

;WITH NameBase 
AS
(
  SELECT t.Name [TestName], f.Name [FieldName], f.GroupId
  FROM [FormFields] f
  INNER JOIN [Tests] t ON f.GroupID = t.ID
)
SELECT @colList = COALESCE(@colList + ',','') + QUOTENAME([FieldName] + '_' + [GroupId])
, @selList = COALESCE(@selList + ',','') + QUOTENAME([FieldName] + '_' + [GroupId]) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME([FieldName] + ' - ' + [TestName])
FROM NameBase

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT [UserName],' + @selList + ' FROM (
SELECT u.Name [UserName], f.Name + '_' + f.GroupId [FieldName], r.RespVal [Response]
FROM Responses r
INNER JOIN [TestUsers] u ON r.UserID = u.ID
INNER JOIN [FormFields] f ON r.FieldID = f.ID) t
PIVOT (MAX([Response]) FOR [FieldName] IN (' + @colList + ')) pvt'

EXECUTE(@sql);
```

I haven't tested that yet, but it should at least point you in the right direction.  I'll try to build a SqlFiddle to test it in a little bit.

Comment: As I understood you, you just told me that what I want to make. But how? Can you give me example?